# How to pass multiple auth ids e.g password and email, to the user_create method of the "webApp2_extras" user model?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, webapp2

```
def create_user(cls, auth_id, unique_properties=None, **user_values):
        """Creates a new user.

        :param auth_id:
            A string that is unique to the user. Users may have multiple
            auth ids. Example auth ids:

            - own:username
            - own:email@example.com
            - google:username
            - yahoo:username
```

Please help explain what I am doing wrong when I just want to pass multiple authentication IDs

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please clarify your question? I'm unsure what you're asking. Thanks

Comment: How to pass multiple auth ids e.g password and email, to the user_create method of the webApp2_extras user model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `User.add_auth_id(auth_id)` function to add additional authentication IDs after the User is created.